# Angular2 switch between components and share the data model

Tags: angular, components, angular2-routing, ng-switch

I have a component. The component is a list of some items. When I click on some item on the list view another component (detail-info view) should appear. What is the best way to replace the first component (list of some items) with the detailed view and from the detailed view I need to be able to go back to the item view (back button/link). What is the best practice to accomplish this in angular2.

Comment: I guess https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service with https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: Thank you for the links. It is very well described. In my main.compnent.html is just: <router-outlet></router-outlet>. The navigation is accomplished with routing rules and it works. But the list of items is not displaying. I have a component <items-comp [items]="items"></items-comp> in which I pass the data ( @select() items: Observable<List<Item>>). I am using Redux. The problem is how can I initiliaze the list of items when redirecting to the item view with Redux.

Comment: Sorry, don't know about Redux.